# How do I use twitter OAuth 2.0 in an external app?

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm reading through the Twitter Dev docs and I don't understand where do I send the authentication request (what's the URL) and how do I encode my login/password? (or does it do so automatically?)

I understand what headers and encodings I need to provide, but I don't know what URL to send the POST requests to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the request to https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token

You can find this information [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/token)